# Disable Save prompt when closing Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to make it so that when a user clicks the "X" in the top right corner of a WORD document, the prompt "would you like to save changes?" does not come up and the document is not saved. I have found many solutions for [Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643164/how-to-disable-saveas-in-ms-word-in-vb-net), but I have not been successful trying to apply them to Word...

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:** I want this to apply to only one document. The .docm is set up as a ReadOnly (to allow Kill-ing itself); it has 2 buttons, 1 for saving as a .pdf form for retain, and 1 to save as a revision and not a completed form. I want to disable the prompt when someone uses the "X" to force saved revision tracking.

Comment: Might help if you added a little context. Do you want this to apply to all documents at all times, or just one specific document? If you set a document's `Saved` property to true then Word will not prompt for a save on closing it, as long as there's been no change since you set that property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this in your `ThisDocument` Object under `MicrosoftWordObjects` for the file in question.

*Make sure it doesn't go into the `Normal` section*

```
Private Sub Document_Close()
    Me.Saved = True
End Sub
```

Putting this in the `Normal` section will turn off the Save As functionality for all documents you open on your instance of Word.

Comment: Thanks so much!

I tried to use ActiveDocument.Saved = True in Document_Close() sub and it didn't work, so I figured that entire premise was wrong... any idea why that wouldn't have worked?

Comment: Glad I could help!  I believe the `ActiveDocument.Saved` assignment won't work because [ActiveDocument is a read-only property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837737.aspx).  The assignment will work if you use `ThisDocument.Saved` or `Me.Saved`.

Comment: Setting `word.ActiveDocument.saved = true` also works, the document is marked as unchanged after this.

Comment: This has worked for a long time, but since I added a "Combo Box (ActiveX Control)", it no longer works. Is there a way to keep the Save prompt from showing up with this?

Comment: Hi @Daevin, I'm not sure what the issue is with the new control.  I recommend asking a new question so it will get a bit more attention.

Comment: Yeah, will do. I was just hoping you might know.